# In a Nested Navigator Structure of Flutter, How do you get the a Specific Navigator?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

I have this problem when I have Nested `Navigator`s. So something like,

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: "/",
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => SomeOneView(),
        '/two': (context) => SomeTwoView(),
        '/three': (context) => SomeThreeView(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class SomeOneView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SomeOneViewState createState() => _SomeOneViewState();
}

class _SomeOneViewState extends State<SomeOneView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.indigo,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          MaterialButton(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Text('Next'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/two'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}



class SomeTwoView extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _SomeTwoViewState createState() => _SomeTwoViewState();
}

class _SomeTwoViewState extends State<SomeTwoView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        // Some implementation
      },
      child: Navigator(
        initialRoute: "two/home",
        onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
          WidgetBuilder builder;
          switch (settings.name) {
            case "two/home":
              builder = (BuildContext context) => HomeOfTwo();
              break;
            case "two/nextpage":
              builder = (BuildContext context) => PageTwoOfTwo();
              break;
          }
          return MaterialPageRoute(builder: builder, settings: settings);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeOfTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          MaterialButton(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Text('Next'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('two/nextpage'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageTwoOfTwo extends StatelessWidget {

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.teal,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          MaterialButton(
            child: Text('Next'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/three'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

So as you can see, I navigate from the Top Most `Navigator` provided by `MaterialApp` going down to the child `Navigator`'s `'two/nextpage'` which should then go to `MaterialApp` `'/three'`. The problem is that doing `onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/three'),` returns the `Navigator` of the current `context` which is the child `Navigator`. I need to access the `MaterialApp`'s `Navigator` to navigate correctly. What is the right way to do this?

Also how to handle the case where the `Navigator` I want to access is somewhere in the middle of a stack of `Navigator`s?

Comment: I actually already tried that approach. I am looking for a better solution. (if there is any)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Most of the time, you'll have only 2 Navigator.

Which means to obtain the nested one, do:

```
Navigator.of(context)
```

And to obtain the root one do:

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true)
```

---

For more complex architecture, the easiest by far is to use GlobalKey (since you'll never read Navigators during *build*)

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> key =GlobalKey();
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> key2 =GlobalKey();

class Foo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: key,
      home: Navigator(
        key: key2,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Which you can then use this way:

```
key.currentState.pushNamed('foo')
```

Comment: could you help me with my problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62807600/flutter-willpopscope-for-nested-navigation

Comment: Where has this answer been all my life... I had to pass callbacks 6 levels deep to push a page to the parent context...THANK YOU!

Comment: Need to read the documentation, I too wasted my time using unnecessary callbacks. :(

Answer (score 8):

Actually you'd have to use nested `Navigator` when you have a sub navigation flow or inner journey. Please read the docs of [nesting navigators](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html#nesting-navigators).

However to get access to root navigator, you can recursively look for the parent `Navigator` from current `Navigator` and return current `Navigator` when it has no parent `Navigator`.

Example:

```
NavigatorState getRootNavigator(BuildContext context) {
  final NavigatorState state = Navigator.of(context);
  try {
    return getRootNavigator(state.context);
  } catch (e) {
    return state;
  }
}

//use it from any widget like
getRootNavigator(context);
```

***EDIT:***

**Solution 1 :**

To get a specific parent `Navigator`, I can think of extending current `Navigator` class to accept an `id` and find the `Navigator` by `id`. Something like:

```
class NavigatorWithId extends Navigator {
  const NavigatorWithId(
      {Key key,
      @required this.id,
      String initialRoute,
      @required RouteFactory onGenerateRoute,
      RouteFactory onUnknownRoute,
      List<NavigatorObserver> observers = const <NavigatorObserver>[]})
      : assert(onGenerateRoute != null),
        assert(id != null),
        super(
          key: key,
          initialRoute: initialRoute,
          onGenerateRoute: onGenerateRoute,
          onUnknownRoute: onUnknownRoute,
          observers: observers,
        );

  // when id is null, the `of` function returns top most navigator
  final int id;

  static NavigatorState of(BuildContext context, {int id, ValueKey<String> key}) {
    final NavigatorState state = Navigator.of(
      context,
      rootNavigator: id == null,
    );
    if (state.widget is NavigatorWithId) {
      // ignore: avoid_as
      if ((state.widget as NavigatorWithId).id == id) {
        return state;
      } else {
        return of(state.context, id: id);
      }
    }

    return state;
  }
}
```

Use `NavigatorWithId` instead of `Navigator` whenever required, like

```
return NavigatorWithId(
  id: 1,
  initialRoute: '/',
  onGenerateRoute: (_) =>
      MaterialPageRoute<dynamic>(builder: (_) => const YourPage()),
)
```

Then access it like:

```
NavigatorWithId.of(context, id: 1)
```

**Solution 2 :**

Pass `ValueKey` to the navigator and make a util function that would match key and return the required `Navigator`.

A function something like

```
NavigatorState getNavigator(BuildContext context, {bool rootNavigator = false, ValueKey<String> key}) {
  assert(rootNavigator != null);
  final NavigatorState state = Navigator.of(
    context,
    rootNavigator: rootNavigator,
  );
  if (rootNavigator) {
    return state;
  } else if (state.widget.key == key) {
    return state;
  }
  try {
    return getNavigator(state.context, key: key);
  } catch (e) {
    return state;
  }
}
```

Use

```
return Navigator(
  key: const ValueKey<String>('Navigator1'),
  initialRoute: '/',
  onGenerateRoute: (_) =>
      MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder: (_) => const RootPage()),
);
```

and access it like

```
getNavigator(context, key: const ValueKey<String>('Navigator1'))
```

The drawback of this method I can see as not all types of keys would be supported.

*Note: I don't claim any of the above solutions to be best or optimal. These are few methods I came up with. If someone can come up with better approach, I'm eager to learn :)*

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, I understand nested navigator. I actually read the docs and if you could see, my code is almost similar to the example on that docs. The only different is that, the reference to the navigator in the docs is passed through a lambda. I don't think that is a good solution so I am asking of a different way to do it.

Comment: Great! All I can think of is to recursively look for root navigator. If anyone could come up with different and better approach, I'm glad to learn :)

Comment: Your solution though I think would work would not handle all cases. how about a situation where the Navigator you would want to access is somewhere in the middle and not the root. For example: Navigator ( TheNavigatorIWantToAcess( AnotherNavigator ( TheNavigatorIAmCurrentlyIn() ) ) ).

Comment: Got it, but the question was to access the `top most navigator` only my friend. Please update the question :)

Comment: Oh yeah sorry about that. Gonna update my question. :)

Comment: That's the best answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

**You can do like this it always finds above navigator and pop**

```
 context.findAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>()?.context.findAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>()?.pop();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use nested navigator pretty commonly when creating a flow which can be dismissed all at once. It needs the parent Navigator(1 level above) to pop the entire flow. Creating a global key and storing it in state management for every nested navigator seemed too much for me. Here's my solution

```
class NestedNavigator {
  /// @param level 0 for current navigator. Same as Navigator.of()
  ///              1 for parent
  ///              >= 2 for grand parent
  static NavigatorState? of(BuildContext context, {int level = 1}) {
    var state = context.findAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>();
    while (state != null && level-- > 0) {
      state = state.context.findAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>();
    }
    return state;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
NestedNavigator.of(context).pop();
```

Of course, if you want a specific navigator, you should definitely store GlobalKey and use it directly instead.

Answer (score 0):

On my app I use that for my nested navigators:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';

extension NavigatorStateExtension on NavigatorState {
  NavigatorState? get parent => context.findAncestorStateOfType<NavigatorState>();
}
```

```dart
return BackButton(
  onPressed: () {
    final NavigatorState navigator = Navigator.of(context);
    if (navigator.canPop()) {
      navigator.pop();
    } else {
      navigator.parent?.pop();
    }
  },
);
```