# How to route to page, without removing BottomNavigationBar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, scoped-model

I'm creating **my first app** in flutter, and i'm having issues with state management. I have a MainPage.dart with **BottomNavigationBar**, and body: with **tabPages[MainTab, ...]**. In the MainTab i have a ListView, and when i click ListView item, it should open details, however **BottomNavigationBar shouldn't be removed**. 
Below i have a design.(I'm using **Scoped Model**).

[image]

> I tried these solutions
>   https://gist.github.com/HansMuller/0e76c54b1f2d4423efbdc2c185e761ef and [How to route to page, without removing BottomNavigationBar in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541827/how-to-route-to-page-without-removing-bottomnavigationbar-in-flutter)
>
> But in those cases, i can't route to page **without** bottom navigation. When i click on FLoatingActionButton: it should open new page **without** bottom navigation (BottomNavigationBar stay always at the bottom, even if i don't want it)

Comment: You can use a nested `Navigator` to achieve this workflow. Look at something like the code for `CupertinoTabScaffold` (which uses a nested `Navigator` internally) or this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55213680/in-a-nested-navigator-structure-of-flutter-how-do-you-get-the-a-specific-naviga

Comment: I need materialApp (So i can't use cupertinoTab). Now i tried solution with Navigator, but now i can't route to page without bottom navigation (In some cases i don't need bottomNavigationBar).

Comment: https://medium.com/@daniyargilimov/lutter-bottomnavigationbar-with-multiple-navigators-725ff013489c

Answer (score 1):

https://medium.com/@daniyargilimov/lutter-bottomnavigationbar-with-multiple-navigators-725ff013489c

here is the working example...