# Flutter WillPopScope for nested Navigation

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-navigation

I have Flutter App with nested Navigator and I want to override "onBackPressed" using `WillPopScope` in my nested screen.

Let's say I have `MainScreen`, `PrimaryScreen`, and `SecondaryScreen`.
`PrimaryScreen` is nested Navigator, it has several screens like `PrimaryOneScreen`, `PrimaryTwoScreen`, and `PrimaryThreeScreen`.

`SecondaryScreen` is also a nested Navigator, just like `PrimaryScreen`, it has 3 screens.

Here the illustration of what i want to achieve

`MainScreen` -> `PrimaryScreen`(`PrimaryOneScreen` -> `PrimaryTwoScreen` -> `PrimaryThreeScreen`)

When my position on `PrimaryTwoScreen`, I want to get back to `PrimaryOneScreen` with overriding "onBackPressed" using `WillPopScope` Widget. But `onWillPop` never called when I press back button, and my screen go back directly to `MainScreen`.

Here are my codes

MainScreen.dart

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MainApp(),
      onGenerateRoute: (settings){
        WidgetBuilder builder;
        switch(settings.name){
          case 'primary' :
            builder = (BuildContext _) => PrimaryScreen();
            break;
          case 'secondary' :
            builder = (BuildContext _) => SecondaryScreen();
            break;
          case 'main' :
            builder = (BuildContext _) => MainApp();
            break;
          default :
            throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
        }

        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: builder,
            settings: settings
        );
      },
    );
  }
}


class MainApp extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'primary');
            },
            child: Text('To Page Primary'),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'secondary');
            },
            child: Text('To Page Secondary'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

PrimaryScreen.dart

```
class PrimaryScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Navigator(
        initialRoute: 'primary/pageone',
        onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings){
          WidgetBuilder builder;
          switch(settings.name){
            case 'primary/pageone' :
              builder = (BuildContext _) => PrimaryOneScreen();
              break;
            case 'primary/pagetwo' :
              builder = (BuildContext _) => PrimaryTwoScreen();
              break;
            case 'primary/pagethree' :
              builder = (BuildContext _) => PrimaryThreeScreen();
              break;
            default :
              throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
          }

          return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: builder,
              settings: settings
          );
        },
      );
  }

}
```

PrimaryOneScreen.dart

```
class PrimaryOneScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Primary Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
           FlatButton(
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'primary/pagetwo');
              },
              child: Text('To Page Two'),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'primary/pagethree');
              },
              child: Text('To Page Three'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

PrimaryTwoScreen.dart

```
class PrimaryTwoScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: ()async{
        print('willPopScope');
        Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: false).pop();
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Secondary Page'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'primary/pageone');
                },
                child: Text('To Page One'),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'primary/pagethree');
                },
                child: Text('To Page Three'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

PrimaryThreeScreen.dart

```
class PrimaryThreeScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Primary Page'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'primary/pageone');
              },
              child: Text('To Page One'),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: (){
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'primary/pagetwo');
              },
              child: Text('To Page Two'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

**EDIT**
I added an image to illustrate what I want to achieve.
[image]

How to pop only on nested navigator?

Thanks!

Comment: try pushReplacementNamed instead of pushNamed

Comment: plus can you add an image for clearer information of your desired output?

Comment: where should I put pushReplacementNamed? on every pushNamed??

Comment: I think pushReplacementNamed is not the solution since it dispose previous route.

Answer (score 3):

When pressing the back button, I think it will use the main navigator of your app, because it doesn't know the nested navigator what you want to interact with.

To solve it, you have to assign a key for your navigator to be able to use it later. And adding a WillPopScope at widget which you use your nested navigator to handle user action.

Based on your example, I added some code. Noting, the maybePop() function will call the WillPopScope of your widget of the nested navigator. If you call pop(), it will pop directly, ignoring the WillPopScope of your widget.

```
class PrimaryScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          if (_navigatorKey.currentState != null) {
            _navigatorKey.currentState!.maybePop();
            return false;
          }

          return true;
        },
        child: Navigator(
          key: _navigatorKey,
          initialRoute: 'primary/pageone',
          onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
            WidgetBuilder builder;
            switch(settings.name){
              case 'primary/pageone' :
                builder = (BuildContext _) => PrimaryOneScreen();
                break;
              case 'primary/pagetwo' :
                builder = (BuildContext _) => PrimaryTwoScreen();
                break;
              case 'primary/pagethree' :
                builder = (BuildContext _) => PrimaryThreeScreen();
                break;
              default :
                throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
            }

            return MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: builder,
              settings: settings
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this link https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31

Check **Use-case : pushReplacementNamed** tag description

Comment: I want to go back from PrimaryTwoScreen to PrimaryOneScreen. If I used pushReplacementNamed to navigate from PrimaryOneScreen to PrimaryTwoScreen, it will dispose PrimaryOneScreen when PrimaryTwoScreen complete animated. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes @fajarainul

Comment: so that is not what I want. Any idea? @Raj Kateshiya